# nfc p2p communication arduino to arduino

Tags: android, arduino, nfc, p2p, ndef

for my master thesis I am currently working in a project that should exchange 
data between two arduino uno by means of a NFC communication p2p using SPI interface.

The shield is a NFC pn532 based, from Elechouse (NFC MODULE V3). Actually it could be the adafruit breakout board but the important thing is the pn532.

I am using this library https://github.com/don/NDEF and it works with arduino to android and android to arduino. According to the creator, It should work also for my purpose.

There's something that initiates the connection between Android and Arduino that is not happening between 2 Arduinos. Unfortunately I think it's something low level in SNEP or LLCP. All that's happening in the PN532 driver.

So here is the point: no one had achieved that, but I don´t think is something huge. I need to know what is missing between two arduino that is happening between arduino and android. The datasheet of PN532/C1 rev. 3.2 should help.

Anyone can help me in that?

Comment: are you sure the spi mode of elechouse nfc working? I have several elechouse nfc module v3, none of them works with spi mode. I2C is working good. But p2p library needs spi.

Comment: That is quite old as a post. I've managed to create a brand new library, and it is working great with the spi. https://github.com/FraunhoferItalia/nfc_p2p. Have you already changed the switches position on the board to get the spi to work? They are set to I2C as default

Comment: Were you able to make connection between Android and 532 in I2C mode or it requires SPI? I have to connect it with both iPhone and Android phone.

Answer (score -1):

Phones have to perform some sort of card emulation to be able to be detected by a reader, as they are not tags. Same story with arduino shields, they are not tags either. I've checked the [adafruit shield](https://www.adafruit.com/products/789) and it doesn't do card emulation because it requires an external Secure Element from NXP. So I'm not sure about your shield but you should check the documentation.

Another risk might be that your project only worked with NXP technology. Android phones with Broadcom NFC chips might not be compatible with your shield/library if it only reads Mifare cards (which are NXP propietary).

Comment: Nah, card emulation is not needed. I've done p2p connections between two PN532 chips without any problems. I was using a commercial library though.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I think I don't need this sort of card emulation anyway I will look at it. Nils Pipenbrick, which software did you use? Could you help me in that?